# remove commit in the middle of a branch

Tags: git

I have branch `develop`, for every new feature I should make new branch based on the this branch.

I had two tasks so I wrote the first feature by starting new branch `feature/Foo`, after completing this feature I start writing the second feature but now I based the new branch on the `feature/Foo` branch. but the problem that I should start the second new branch from the `develop` branch and not `feature/Foo` branch

checkout this (**what I did**)

```
 A => B => C                 // develop branch
             => D            // feature/Foo branch
                   => E      // feature/Bar branch
```

what I should Have is this (**what I'm trying to achieve**)

```
 A => B => C                 // develop branch
             => D            // feature/Foo branch
             => E            // feature/Bar branch
```

now how could I remove the commit `D` from `feature/Bar` so that the branch start directly from the `develop` branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the two-argument form of `rebase --onto`:

```
# from feature/Bar
git rebase --onto C D
```

In plain English, the above says to give `feature/Bar` a new *base*, beginning at the commit whose *parent* is `D` (i.e. replace the `E` commit).  This new base should be placed on top of commit `C`.

Note that this option rewrites history, and so should be avoided in the event that `feature/Bar` already be shared by multiple people.